# Suppress tensorflow-metal initialization messages

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I have a macbook pro m1 max and installed tensorflow via [tensowflow-apple-download](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

I get the following logs every time I run a script that uses keras or tensorflow:

```
>>>  python script.py
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Max

systemMemory: 32.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 10.67 GB

2022-09-06 02:35:38.603010: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-09-06 02:35:38.603133: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
2022-09-06 02:35:38.659578: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2022-09-06 02:35:38.684142: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
```

Most of the logs are irrelevant and I was able to suppress some by:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

However I can't disable these logging info:

```
>>>  python script.py
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Max

systemMemory: 32.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 10.67 GB
```

Is there any way to make keras and tensorflow-metal silent? I don't want these logs.

I have already tried without success:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(2)

import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Note: Uninstalling tensorflow-metal seems to suppress the logging info, however the solution is not optimal since tensorflow will run on CPU instead of GPU...

```
>>> pip uninstall tensorflow-metal
```

I think the logging present is now due to calling keras `Sequential()`:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
```

Comment: Apparently, what you now want to suppress aren't log messages, as they do not have any of the context information at the front of them (date and severity) like the other output lines you show do.  They are therefore likely just `print()` statements that are going directly to `stdout`.  I'm not familiar with the package in question, so I don't know if it might provide a way to suppress that information, but adjusting the logging system isn't going to help.  You can just suppress all output with `python script.py > /dev/null`., but I'm guessing that that is more brute force than what you want.

Comment: Ohh I understand!! I'll try to find a way to surpress prints from tensorflow/keras! Thank you :)

Comment: news? looking for the same fix

Comment: These messages are not written to `stdout` I think, because I can't capture them with [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout). This has already been reported [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728856), and hopefully Apple will provide a fix soon.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to suppress these Warnings (W) and Informational(I) messages using the code below:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import tensorflow as tf
```

Please put these code on top line of the entire code before importing `TensorFlow` and try again.

**Without using environment variable**(TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL):

[image]

**After using environment variable**(TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL='2'):

[image]

**Note:** If you will set the environment variable to 3, All the messages `(1 - informational(I), 2 - warnings(W) and 3- errors(E))` will not be logged during code execution.

It is recommended to use latest python and TensorFlow version in your system.