# Cannot suppress Tensorflow warnings in Jupyter Notebook no matter what I do

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to suppress warnings (specifically from `tensorflow`) in my Jupyter noteboook since they're not relevant and end up just clogging up my screen and making it super difficult to read the stuff I actually need to read. I've tried everything below, the warnings just won't stop:

- `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`
- `warnings.simplefilter('ignore')`
- `logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True`
- `logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`
- `logging.disable(logging.WARNING)`
- `os.environ['PYTHONWARNING'] = 'ignore'`
- `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = 3`

I even tried updating my `ipython_config.py` file with:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import warnings',
    'warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")',
]
```

And even tried making a context manager like this:

```
class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stderr.close()
        sys.stderr = self._original_stderr

with HiddenPrints():
    # rest of my code
```

For context, I get this warning when I import `spacy`:

> 2023-05-23 14:42:41.997371: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations. To enable the following instructions:
> AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate
> compiler flags.

And I get a *ton* of these warnings when I call a function that builds and fits a LSTM `keras` model:

> 2023-05-23 14:48:30.399777: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0]
> (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error
> and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a
> value for placeholder tensor
> 'gradients/split_2_grad/concat/split_2/split_dim' with dtype int32

I've seen some posts suggest using Jupyter's `%%capture` magic command, but my understanding is that would capture *all* output not just warnings which I don't want. Any ideas?

Comment: naively, could you fix the warnings? they might be important

Comment: Please share a toy example of a shareable, minimal reproducible example, as detailed in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so that those knowledgeable can try the tricks we know about and put you on track. There are different levels of the stdout/stderr pipes to address. This is already partly covered **in general** in several places in StackOverflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23692951/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52559560/8508004) & others. And so if you want more specific advice, post an improved question.

Comment: Hi @vudupins, Did you try using `import os`, `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'` before importing the tensorflow in your code to suppress the warning messages? Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76315324/21904865) for your reference. Let us know if the issue still persists.